# what is the meaning of Future<Database> get db async() in flutter

Tags: android, database, flutter

I am following a tutorial about using Sqlite database in flutter from this link 
[SQFlite Database in flutter](https://medium.com/@mohamedraja_77/sqflite-database-in-flutter-c0b7be83bcd2)

but I get confused in some parts of this tutorial as following :

first what is the meaning of get db after Future. I don't understand the structure of function also when this function will execute? he doesn't call it in the tutorial ?

```
Future<Database> get db async {
    if(_db != null)
      return _db;
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }
```

second in this function 
  he called method _onCreate but he doesn't pass any parameters 
why and what does that mean ?

```
initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "test.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }
```

Comment: So, did you check the answer, find what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tutorial would be easier
[tutorial](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite)

Anyway
`Future<Database> get db` - it's not field, it's just getter
So, when you call `DBHelper.db` - it checks `_db` if it isn't null and return `Future` with `_db` field.

Regarding `onCreate: _onCreate`
parameter `onCreate` in `openDatabase` method need 2 parameters (you can see this into sources) 
`typedef FutureOr OnDatabaseCreateFn(Database db, int version)`
method `_onCreate` need the same parameters
`void _onCreate(Database db, int version)`

In such cases you can write `onCreate: _onCreate` - without parameters

I hope I've answered you questions. Write if something isn't clear